# System crashed suddenly and does not boot after that --because of ubuntu only

Tags: shutdown

I was watching video on youtube and suddely system crashed and then i tried to restart the machine but it just gets to the dual boot menu and after that shuts down again..

I think this is because of ubuntu only...Because i am able to run Ubuntu from Live CD..

PLease tell me if there is anything i can do...

Right now i am posting this question from my desktop..

Comment: When you say it suddenly "shut down", do you mean it crashed? Immediately powered off? If it's not booting from the harddisk, there may be some hardware damage to the disk that's stopping it from booting (and that caused the crash in the first place).

Comment: Yes, it got crashed..Editing the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a hard disk failure since your system work perfectly well with a Live-CD. You can partially fix this by using this command from the Live-CD :

```
sudo e2fsck -cy /dev/sda1
```

You have to change /dev/sda1 by the name of the partition of your system (and make sure it is not mounted), if you don't know what is it, you can use :

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Which will show you all the partition on your system. This operation will take a long time and basicilly will add dammaged sectors of your partition to a list so that the filesystem will don't access them again (that will prevent the system from crashing). Since the data on damaged sector will be lost your system may not start even after the fix, in this case save all your important datas with the Live-CD and reinstall on the fixed filesystem (don't format or you'll lose the list of bad sectors and you may crash during the installation). You should do it to every partition of your damaged disk.

In any case make sure to save all your important datas.

Comment: Nyamiou, thanks for your reply...Actually i restarted my machine for a couple of times after booting with Live CD and now it is working...+1 for your answer